# Is it possible to compile .NET IL code to machine code?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, compiler-construction

I would like to distribute my .NET programs without the .NET framework. Is it possible to compile a .NET program to machine code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you can precompile using Ngen.exe, however this does not remove the CLR dependence.

You must still ship the IL assemblies as well, the only benefit of Ngen is that your application can start without invoking the JIT, so you get a real fast startup time.

According to CLR Via C#:

> Also, assemblies precompiled using
>   Ngen are usually slower than JIT'ed
>   assemblies because the JIT compiler
>   can optimize to the targets machine
>   (32-bit? 64-bit? Special registers?
>   etc), while NGEN will just produce a
>   baseline compilation.

EDIT:

There is some debate on the above info from CLR Via C#, as some say that you are required to run Ngen on the target machine only as part of the install process.

Comment: Why are ngen assemblies slower? ngen is invoked on the target machine, so that should not actually make a difference.
Oh, and ngen is not the actual answer to the question.

Comment: Ngen is invoked by the developer to precompile the app, not on the target machine. Please read the section on Ngen in CLR Via C#.

Comment: Jon, that depends. `ngen` can be invoked by the installation process on the target machine, and as far as I know this is in fact done for various Microsoft products implemented in .NET.

Comment: However, NGen can made into part of the application install process, allowing it to compile to the target machine, I'll edit my post.

Comment: EDIT to my comment: you're in fact wrong (and so was I), `ngen` *has* to be invoked on the target machine. `ngen` installs a native image in the *machine-local* GAC! Precompiling on the developer's machine would be useless.

Comment: I guess the most prominent example ngen'ing its files on the target machine is the .NET Framework 2.0 itself - next time you install it somewhere, take a look at the text it displays :)

Comment: And don't forget paint.NET. When it states it optimizes for your computer during installation, it's using ngen.

Comment: Also, NGEN can't take into account the current value of any static variables, where JIT can. We rely on the JIT to actually omit lines of code from the machine instruction based on the value of readonly static variables.

Answer (score 20):

Remotesoft has one:
[Salamander .NET Linker](http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/)

I don't have any experience with it though.

Comment: this question has been asked before and again this is the only correct answer. being, it is possible but at a price.

Answer (score 7):

There are some third party tools that do this, e.g.

- http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/
- http://www.xenocode.com/

Answer (score 5):

Another (expensive and proprietary, licenses start at $1599) product that can do this is [Xenocode Postbuild](http://www.xenocode.com/Products/Postbuild/). Haven't used it myself though, with it costing about the gross national product of a small African country and all...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can now! Recently Microsoft announced **.NET Native**, a piece of technology that compiles your application with .NET Native runtime (they call it MRT) into one binary (actually one executable and one dynamic library).

See links:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/04/02/announcing-net-native-preview.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/04/24/dotnetnative-performance.aspx

Comment: Note that it doesn't support Desktop

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to compile .NET IL code
>   to machine code?

Yes, but the .NET Framework does it for you at runtime (default) or at install time (ngen). Among other reasons, this IL -> machine code is done separately on each install machine so it can be optimized for that particular machine.

> I would like to distribute my .NET
>   programs without the .NET framework.
>   Is it possible to compile a .NET
>   program to machine code?

No, for all intents and purposes you cannot do this. The 3rd party workarounds may work in some scenarios, but by then I wouldn't really consider it "managed code" or ".NET" anymore.

Answer (score 2):

There is [IL2CPU](http://www.gocosmos.org/Docs/Dev/IL2CPU/index.EN.aspx) for the compilation part.

Comment: I'd love a standalone executable of this compiler! But from what I read it's integrated with VS and no longer produce Windows' executables.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is possible. You can make a prejitted assembly but you still need the framework.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not: That's the task of the JIT compiler.

However, you could use ClickOnce or Windows Installer to deploy it so that the missing  framework isn't such a big problem: you could tell the installer to download the Framework and install it.

Comment: Excuse me but just getting started in VBnet. It does seem you do not have to download Framework. At compiling the vbnet project you can include the Framework option. Mine had some errors when deploying but the idea seems to be that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you just concerned with the size of deploying the Framework, you might read up on [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SmallestDotNetOnTheSizeOfTheNETFramework.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Look at MONO project: mono command with --aot option. http://www.mono-project.com/AOT

Answer (score 0):

I'd always thought it would be cool to compile c# to machine code directly without the CLR dependency though....

Answer (score 0):

For those using .NET Core or more recent .NET (5+), there is a **Self-Contained deployment option**, which is described in MSDN as

> The output publishing folder contains all components of the app,
> including the .NET libraries and target runtime. The app is isolated
> from other .NET apps and doesn't use a locally installed shared
> runtime. The user of your app isn't required to download and install
> .NET.

Steps to prepare a self-contained deployment:

- Switch the solution configuration from Debug to Release.
- Right click on the project in Solution Explorer and select Publish.
- Select Folder as the Target and click Next.
- Select again Folder as the Specific target and click Next.
- In the Location tab, browse your target binaries path and click Finish.
- In the Publish tab, click the small pencil icon (Edit Target runtime) at the
  end of the Target runtime row.
- In the Profile settings dialog (displayed below), Select Self-contained from the Deployment mode combobox.
- Choose your runtime from the Target runtime combobox.
- (Optionally) Specify the output path of the binaries from the Target location combobox.
- Click Save.
- When you click the Publish button in the Publish tab, your binaries will be
  created.

[image: Self-contained deployment]

There are other deployment options such as Azure, Docker Container Registry etc. but for simplicity I chose the Folder option. Note that the steps and the screenshot belongs to VS 2019.

For more info see [Self-Contained Publishing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained).

Answer (score 0):

.NET 7+ supports AOT. For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot.

---

### Publish Native AOT using the CLI

1. Add `<PublishAot>true</PublishAot>` to your project file.

   This property enables Native AOT compilation during publish. It also enables dynamic code-usage analysis during build and editing. It's preferable to put this setting in the project file rather than passing it on the command line, since it controls behaviors outside publish.

   ```xml
   <PropertyGroup>
       <PublishAot>true</PublishAot>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```
2. Publish the app for a specific runtime identifier using `dotnet publish -r <RID>`.

   The following example publishes the app for Windows as a Native AOT application on a machine with the required prerequisites installed.

   `dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release`

   The following example publishes the app for Linux as a Native AOT application. A Native AOT binary produced on Linux machine is only going to work on same or newer Linux version. For example, Native AOT binary produced on Ubuntu 20.04 is going to run on Ubuntu 20.04 and later, but it isn't going to run on Ubuntu 18.04.

   `dotnet publish -r linux-arm64 -c Release`

The app is available in the publish directory and contains all the code needed to run in it, including a stripped-down version of the coreclr runtime.

---

### Limitations in the .NET Native AOT deployment model

#### .NET 7

Native AOT is targeted towards console-type apps. Only a limited number of libraries are fully compatible with Native AOT.

#### .NET 8+

AOT support in .NET 8 is more comprehensive than in .NET 7. However, there are still some limitations. For more information, see [Limitations of Native AOT deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot#limitations-of-native-aot-deployment).

---

### Platform/architecture restrictions

The following table shows supported compilation targets.

#### .NET 7

| Platform | Supported architecture |
| --- | --- |
| Windows | x64, Arm64 |
| Linux | x64, Arm64 |

#### .NET 8+

| Platform | Supported architecture | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Windows | x64, Arm64 |  |
| Linux | x64, Arm64 |  |
| macOS | x64, Arm64 |  |
| iOS | Arm64 | Experimental support |
| iOSSimulator | x64, Arm64 | Experimental support |
| tvOS | Arm64 | Experimental support |
| tvOSSimulator | x64, Arm64 | Experimental support |
| MacCatalyst | x64, Arm64 | Experimental support |
| Android | x64, Arm64 | Experimental, no built-in Java interop |

---