# Where should I save the public key used for xml signature verification?

Tags: c#, xml, rsa, signing

I'd like to provide a simple, unencrypted xml-file as the configuration file for my desktop application (winforms, .NET 4.0, C#). I would, however, like to ensure that any configuration file used by the app is from me. For this, I'm thinking of [Xml Signing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745.aspx), which seems to fit my requirements very well.

My only remaining question then is: How should I store the public key within my app to perform the verification of the configuration file? Embedding it into the app is my guess, but exactly how should this be done to prevent someone from simply opening the binary with a decompiler and replacing my key with his/her own?

I'm not looking for anything super secure, because I know I can't make it 100% certain anyways.

Comment: If you are going to embed the key in your code there is no 100% fool proof way of protecting your application from being decompiled and modified, if someone wants do this they will be able to. But you can obfuscate your code which won't prevent people from decompiling your code, it will just make it that little bit harder. And like you yourself said, your not looking for anything super secure :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I protect my .NET assemblies from decompilation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478230/how-can-i-protect-my-net-assemblies-from-decompilation)

Comment: If one will bother decompiling/recompiling your assembly they will simply *remove* the check altogether... Otherwise - it is *public* key, there is no reason to hide it - just include into your app if you want to validate configuration from non-tampered-with version of your program.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Alexei. It had quite a bit of useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, there is no 100% fool proof way of protecting your application from decompilation, but you can obsfuscate your application using a tool such as [Dotfuscator](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview)

Answer (score 0):

I would use windows cert stores to store any keys
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.aspx
And windows Data protection API to store it in memory while your program is executing.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_API
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx