# Secure an Asp.Net MVC 4 on local IIS8

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-8

I have developed an asp.net MVC4 and i want to sell it to a costumer but i will install it on his server IIS8 .

I have installed it on iis8 and it run perfect from remote and local machine.
But any body can see my code in the server machine.

I tried to use permission file but any body can modify it.

**How can i protect my code and don't allow other to see it?**

Comment: How did you installed it?

Comment: Don't host it on their servers.

Comment: you should not host your solution in their servers, [AppHarbor](http://AppHarbor.com) for example is free and it will give you everything you need, including free database and several other services to improve your web application

Comment: i know that's bad to host on their server but the costumer can't use internet : it's intranet solution.
@balexandre thank you for AppHarbor I like it

Comment: @moezsm then the best way would be to create a Windows Application to be installed in the server and then the web application would be simply use as a client, all stuff will happen in the windows app in the server, as you could expose API so all clients could connect.

Comment: The real problem is that the customer haven't internet access he want to use only his local intranet structure (old structure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you install it. You can deploy `Precompiled application output`. This option will not include the source code and you can have a merged assembly dll or single page wise assembly in bin folder.
This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227976(v=vs.90).aspx) can be helpul, check this out.

### Edit

If you want more than a precompiled option which can be decompiled. You can read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2478504/3383479) to figure out how you can achieve the goal.

Comment: Which can then be easily viewed with a decompiler, several of which are available for free.

Comment: Well running a Precompiled application seems to be sufficient thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After compile your application, you can publish only the necessary, the folders "Controllers, Models, obj, Properties, Filters and App_Start" no longer required, those folders are included in yourApp.dll file in "Bin" folder