# How can i protect my dll from decompiler?

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation, code-security

I want to protect my `dll` from `decompile` for that i have created `dll` in `release mode` and also remove .pub feature at `dll` creating time. 
I have also read about `obfuscator` tool but i am not able to protect my `dll`. 
Is there any one know how to protect `dll from decompile`?
I have checked answer of [How can I protect my .NET assemblies from decompilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478230/how-can-i-protect-my-net-assemblies-from-decompilation) but it is not providing proper answer and provide only description that you can't make secure your dll code...

Comment: I think you can't protect from decompiling, what you can do is using some obfuscator, such as Dotfuscator.

Comment: @rcs i have tried crypto obfuscator but not get success.

Comment: @Alberto i have also tried to make duplicate copy with encrypted dll but every time when i use any decompiler then my code dll get open..

Answer (score 1):

You can't. What you can do is obfuscate the code, but it still can be decompiled.

Here is a tool for this:

http://www.9rays.net/Category/55-spicesnet-obfuscator.aspx

Comment: if i am not able to stop decompilation of dll then what obfuscate will do?

Comment: I have downloaded this software and obfuscate my dll but i don't get any change in that dll and my code is still visible without any encryption..

Comment: Your code will still be visible, you can't avoid that. Just that it becomes harder to understand.

Comment: @rcs with .NET Refractor decompile tool it will show proper managed code. after obfucation..

Comment: @Shirish When a new obfuscation technique appears, new tools to de-obfuscate will show up, you can't stop that. Read the duplicate question to find out why it's useless to worry about it.