# Good obfuscator for VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I've already tried EazFuscator and Dotfuscator but are bad! I was able to easily read the source and pay it, and frankly I'm tired of the people that I copy the software. 
I ask you which obfuscator use, at least to protect all the software by beginners.

Comment: Per the close reasons, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow."

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I agree its off topic, but there is more than a few question about this topic. How do we determine which ones to close?

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR - they should all be closed.  Some have just been around for a long time because Stack Overflow's policy used to allow them, and there are millions of questions here that need to be reviewed.

Comment: of course, each such question may be perceived as offtop but, really, i cannot understand people who try to downvote such immediately ... in this case you simply reject new people on SO and make it not so open minded and open source like it was supposed to be ... i really believe that closing of the questions without downvotes should be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the great Joel Coehoorn ... you can read more here

[How can I protect my .NET assemblies from decompilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478230/how-can-i-protect-my-net-assemblies-from-decompilation)

One thing to keep in mind is that you want to do this in a way that makes business sense. To do that, you need to define your goals. So, exactly what are your goals?

Preventing piracy? That goal is not achievable. Even native code can be decompiled or cracked; the multitude of warez available online (even products like Windows and Photoshop) is proof of that.

If you can't prevent piracy, then how about merely reducing it? This, too, is misguided. It only takes one person cracking your code for it to be available to everyone. You have to be lucky every time. The pirates only have to be lucky once.

On another note, I would recommend SmartAssembly by RedGate. Ive used this before and its great compared to others. Please note that like any obfuscator, you cannot stop someone cracking your software if they are determined to do so.

You can get more information here...

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/