# How to protect Windows Store app from decompilation?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime

I'm developing a windows store app using C#. I know that all store apps are installed under C:\Program Files\WindowsApps.

Is there any way to protect it from decompilation by someone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this link: [How can I protect my .NET assemblies from decompilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478230/how-can-i-protect-my-net-assemblies-from-decompilation)

The question asked in the link is same as yours, you can refer to the replies to understand how you can protect your code from getting decompiled.