# What should I do with my software that uses multiple exe files stored in the same directory

Tags: c#, c++, exe, executable

I am typing a software that uses `.exe` files programmed in a separate language. The software is in `C#`, the `.exe` files in `C++`.
Is there a way I can change those standalone `.exe` files into something that is non-executable for any given user but can still be used by my `C#` program?

If that is not feasible, then, is it possible to build a project/solution that uses multiple languages into one executive program?

Comment: You could turn the C++ code into a library and call that library from your C# code.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you, Ill do some research on how to do that, Sorry I'm not that familiar with this language and just learning :))

Comment: I would recommend porting the code over. It will be a good learning exercise if nothing else. Failing that, it is possible to load a c++ dll from within C#. I wouldn't recommend this, but it will be another learning experience.
If your goal here is to learn, rather than ship software, perhaps you should forget about "protecting" the code and focus on learning what you will need to ship software.
This SO question highlights the issues fairly well.

tldr: nobody wants your source code.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478230/how-can-i-protect-my-net-assemblies-from-decompilation

Comment: Are you talking executables or dynamic linked libraries (DLL).  Executables have no relationship to their creation language.  You could have executables created by Visual Basic or Fortran.  The OS must be used to execute them.

Comment: @gburton ill check that out too and see which one would work better in my situation, but I'm glad you told me about these new ways so I learn about them.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Most language implementations use a runtime support library, which definitely links the executable to the creation language.

Comment: @MSalters, so given any executable, it's source language can be determined?  Does this include mixed languages, e.g. Fortran & C?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Generally, yes, and you can determine the compiler too. It's far easier when the support library is in a DLL (or a few DLLs, for mixed languages)