# how can i protect CIL ( Common Intermediate language ) assembly from Decompiling

Tags: c#, .net, decompiling

can i convert CIL assembly files (.net exe files) to native exe files or exist a tool that protect or avoid from easy decompiling to magar source ? ( Not just Dotfuscator Community Edition )?

Comment: as for .net check if it suits http://www.mono-project.com/AOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this tool called [NGen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx) where you can compile your MSIL Assembly into native code.

Comment: Actually Ngen isn't the best choice for decompile protection - assemblies had to be ngen-ed on target machine and each time a dependecy updates (e.g. core framework lib) it is good practice to again  ngen source assemblies to omit broken dependencies. See this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140750/is-it-possible-to-compile-net-il-code-to-machine-code).